# How do I test if Rack::Cache is functioning with Sinatra app on Heroku with memcache?

Tags: ruby, caching, heroku, memcached, sinatra

I'm making a web app where many users will be viewing a Google map, with updates on the map pulled in through ajax requests to the server.  I want the response that is sent to the users to be cached, because it involves scraping data from an outside server, and it only needs to update every 2-3 minutes.

So, as soon as one person requests the data, I want all subsequent requests from all other users to be pulled in from the cache for the next 2-3 minutes.  I followed [this tutorial](http://henrik.nyh.se/2012/07/sinatra-with-rack-cache-on-heroku/),  which details how to set up Rack::Cache and the Dalli gem in Sinatra with Heroku, and when I ran a test on a page set up with the following,

```
cache_control :public, max_age: 3000
```

I can see the cache headers come through correctly (using Google Chrome Developer Tools), but if I hit refresh, or if I request the page from another computer, the content was clearly regenerated (I put a Time.now output).  However, if I go to another page, then retype the URL, the content is not regenerated.  I think the browser is caching the result, but not the memcache server?  Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how caching works?

Answer (score 0):

For people who come upon this question, here are some threads which may help you solve your issue (helped me).

"refresh" in your browser, causes a "Cache-Control: max-age=0":
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rack-cache/sWHyu4pYwKw

Clearing cache and removing cache directory (this worked for me):
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5245

Adding specs for it with rspec / other
[Sinatra, Rack::Test, and Conditional GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728576/sinatra-racktest-and-conditional-get-requests)